# How did Peggy get the bullet wounds on her shoulder?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agent-carter

In *Agent Carter*, Daniel Sousa discovers some bullet wounds on Agent Carter's back. When did she get shot. Was this somewhere in the captain America movie or before that?

Comment: *"Where did those bullet wounds come from."* ..bullets?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Probably bullets shot from a gun

Comment: @thorkia Is it, buh... buh?

Comment: I imagine this will be covered in a later episode.

Comment: Watch the movie and see??

Answer (score 2):

As of this week's episode "The Iron Ceiling", the scars on Peggy's shoulder are simply a plot device that allowed Sousa to realize

> that the mysterious blonde from the club is actually Peggy.

Without that evidence, there is literally no way for Sousa or anyone else to connect Peggy and the other woman... short of her confessing, which is unlikely.

Now, that said, we will likely hear an explanation for the scars when (or if) Sousa confronts Peggy in a later episode. Until then, we can only speculate that she was shot twice in the shoulder at some point during the war.

**UPDATE:** As of the season 1 (series?) finale, no explanation was given for the scars. Unless they're explained later somehow, we have to assume that they serve two purposes story-wise - A) a plot device as mentioned above, and B) something to show that Peggy saw action during the war.

Comment: Also, with her seeing combat for as much as 3 years before Captain America: First Avenger (possibly through the SOE, officially under FANY) and then continued to serve in an intelligence and combat capacity with the howling commandos, she has had plenty of time to be shot.